# How should one argument of a Python function that doesn't change be set?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a function that is called many times. Most of its arguments change, but one remains the same. Is there a way of not having to include it as an argument?

```
# in a loop that changes index
data.variable(index = index, name = "el_1_pt",   value = event.el_pt[0])
data.variable(index = index, name = "el_1_eta",  value = event.el_eta[0])
data.variable(index = index, name = "el_1_phi",  value = event.el_phi[0])
data.variable(index = index, name = "jet_1_pt",  value = event.jet_pt[0])
data.variable(index = index, name = "jet_1_eta", value = event.jet_eta[0])
data.variable(index = index, name = "jet_1_phi", value = event.jet_phi[0])
data.variable(index = index, name = "jet_1_e",   value = event.jet_e[0])
data.variable(index = index, name = "jet_2_pt",  value = event.jet_pt[1])
data.variable(index = index, name = "jet_2_eta", value = event.jet_phi[1])
data.variable(index = index, name = "jet_2_phi", value = event.jet_eta[1])
data.variable(index = index, name = "jet_2_e",   value = event.jet_e[1])
data.variable(index = index, name = "met",       value = event.met_met)
data.variable(index = index, name = "met_phi",   value = event.met_phi)
```

You can see that the argument that doesn't change is `index`. Is there any way for me to not have to specify it as an argument for the function and to have less text used?

Comment: refer to this great [tutorial](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)

Comment: You might `zip()` those names and values, then loop over that.

Comment: Is `data` something you can modify? `index` seems to be the kind of state that can be added to the instance calling `variable`, which then looks at its internal state for the value rather than taking it as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use partial to create a partial function at each loop:

```
from functools import partial
for index in indexes:
    variable = partial(data.variable, index=index)
    variable(name="el_1_pt", value=event.el_pt[0])
    variable(name="el_1_eta", value=event.el_eta[0])
    variable(name="el_1_phi", value=event.el_phi[0])
    variable(name="jet_1_pt", value=event.jet_pt[0])
    variable(name="jet_1_eta", value=event.jet_eta[0])
    variable(name="jet_1_phi", value=event.jet_phi[0])
    variable(name="jet_1_e", value=event.jet_e[0])
    variable(name="jet_2_pt", value=event.jet_pt[1])
    variable(name="jet_2_eta", value=event.jet_phi[1])
    variable(name="jet_2_phi", value=event.jet_eta[1])
    variable(name="jet_2_e", value=event.jet_e[1])
    variable(name="met", value=event.met_met)
    variable(name="met_phi", value=event.met_phi)
```

Comment: That just seems to split it into two separate lines. How does that help?

Comment: The problem does not need this importable module in order to solve it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 no, it's doing one line to set the index for all of the other 14 calls.

Answer (score 1):

Write a loop to execute your function without explicitly writing down all function calls.

Suppose that `name_vals == ["el_1_pt", "el_1_eta", ...]` and that `event_vals == [event.el_pt[0], event.el_eta[0], ...]`.

`zip` those arguments and iterate over them:

```
for index in indexes:
    for name, event in zip(name_vals, event_vals):
        data.variable(index, name, event)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Index is not _always_ the same, but within one iteration of a loop it is the same. This only works for one fixed value. Unless I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @R.Murray I'll wait for the author to clarify.

Comment: @R.Murray Yes, that's right. I can't use simply a default value within the scope of the function. I'm trying to say to Python: "For all of the following function calls, this argument is going to be the same."

Comment: @d3pd alright, thanks for the clarification. I adjusted my answer.